# Relation between the sum of the values of a polynomial $f$ over a finite field, and the additive character sum with $f$ as the polynomial argument

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, characters, exponential-sum

Let $F$ be a finite field, let $f(T) \in F[T]$ and let $\psi$ be the canonical additive character of $F$. If $\sum_{x \in F}f(x) = 0$, what can we say of $\sum_{x \in F} \psi(f(x))$?

Comment: Not much in general I'm afraid. $\sum_{x\in F}f(x)$ will vanish, when $f$ is a constant, in which case the character sum has maximal absolute value. But the former sum vanishes in many cases also for a linear polynomial, and then so does the exponential sum.